# Specifying FileInputStream relative path

Tags: linux, servlets, fileinputstream

I have properties directory on my linux machine under:

```
/home/webserver/tomcat6/properties
```

and in it I have:

```
js.db.properties
js.ldap.properties
```

Servlet calling these property files is under:

```
/home/webserver/tomcat6/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/myServlet.class
```

I am trying to go 4 directories up to get to properties files.

```
FileInputStream ldapfis = new FileInputStream("../../../../properties/js.ldap.properties");
```

I am getting:

```
Encountered following error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../../../../properties/js.ldap.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you type `ls foo`, it doesn't search the file 'foo' in the same directory as the executable or dynamic library which implements the ls command. It searches it in the current directory, i.e. the directory from which you launched the `ls` command. The same goes for Java.

`new FileInputStream("../../../../properties/js.ldap.properties")`will search for the file by starting at the directory from which the `java` command, used to start Tomcat, was executed.

The location of the class containing this line of code is completely irrelevant. BTW, most of the time, the .class file is in a jar or war file, or both.